BiPredicate and how to use it
I'm struggling to understand when I should use a BiPredicate instead of a function.
For instance, let's say I want to create a simple String verification, as s1.equals(s2). Of course, I can create a function that receives two params, checks if s1 isn't null and keep going. Alternatively, in my utilities class, create a static final BiPredicate<String, String>, compare them there and then import it into my main class use wherever needed. But if I create a function, inside the utils instead of a BiPredicate, and make it public, wouldn't it work just fine as well?
I've implemented both , I just would like to get an alternative viewpoint about it.

A function doesn't take two arguments. I don't really understand your question.

I think the question is about using a regular method vs using the BiPredicate SAM type to hold a function.

Are you asking about opinions? what exactly is your question here? are you looking for something similar to this ?

They aren’t comparable. A Predicate returns boolean: a Function doesn’t. A BiPredicate has two arguments: a Function has one. Your question doesn’t make sense.

@user207421 'function' in the context of the question seems more of a synonym to 'method' I believe.

Yeah @knittl, you are right, it's exactly what I've meant.

In that case it makes even less sense, as BiPredicate is a function.

Real life example

BiPredicate<T, U> is a functional interface (a SAM type) with the signature boolean test(T t, U u). When a method accepts a SAM-typed argument, you can pass an explicit implementation of the class, a lambda expression, or a method ref.
If you don't need to pass your function around and invoke it from other places, stay with a plain old function. But if you need another method to receive a predicate, you will need to encode this into a type.
Let's quickly look at some examples:
class MyClass {
  public static boolean stringEquals(final String s1, final String s2) {
    return s1.equals(s2);
  }
}

final BiPredicate<String, String> lambda = (a, b) -> MyClass.stringEquals(a, b);
final BiPredicate<String, String> lambda2 = (a, b) -> a.equals(b);
final BiPredicate<String, String> ref = MyClass::stringEquals;
final BiPredicate<String, String> ref2 = String::equals;
final BiPredicate<String, String> anonymous = new BiPredicate<>() {
  @Override boolean test(final String x, final String y) {
    return MyClass.stringEquals(x, y);
  }
};
final BiPredicate<String, String> anonymous2 = new BiPredicate<>() {
  @Override boolean test(final String x, final String y) {
    return x.equals(y);
  }
};

final boolean same = lambda.test("yes", "yes");
final boolean same2 = lambda2.test("no", "no");
final boolean different = ref.test("yes", "no");
final boolean different2 = ref2.test("yes", "no");
final boolean equal = anonymous.test("maybe", "maybe");
final boolean equal2 = anonymous2.test("maybe", "maybe");

Say you are writing a component that needs to compare strings, but you want users of your component to decide on how strings should be compared (String#equals, Objects#equals, String#equalsIgnoreCase). You could define your method as follows:
class MyComponent {
  public boolean compare(final String s1, final String s2, final BiPredicate<String, String> pred) {
    return pred.test(s1, s2);
  }
}


final boolean truthy = component.compare("yes", "YES", String::equalsIgnoreCase);
final boolean falsy = component.compare("yes", "YES", String::equals);
// or something completely different:
final boolean result = component.compare("yes", "maybe", (a, b) -> a.length()*2 == b.length()+1);


Maybe a good example would be showing a method that receives a BiPredicate as an argument. Then you can change the way the objects are compared.

Thank you! So, if I understand, it's more usefull use it, when I need to do something, like a string comparation, but I can do it in diferent ways acording to the situation. However, if I just need to compair, a String, without any special trick, even if I need it into multiples classes, is it better just use a normal old function.

The main difference between a BiPredicate<T,U> and a BiFunction<T,U,Boolean> is that it is more "specialized" and has a more explicit meaning that it is expected to be use as a predicate.
By "specialized", I mean that you get methods to combine Predicates between them out of the box (like and, negate or or) that you don't get with Functions.
